# 3-way dimmer not dimming

Tags: dimmer-switch

Just had our basement finished and one of the dimmers (3-way with a single non-dimming switch at the other end) is not working properly. Before I call our contractor back, I thought I’d try to fix it myself. See pics below.

- Dimmer is not dimming but it does turn lights on and off
- Lights seem to only turn on and off if the single non-dimming switch is first in the “on” position. Otherwise, the lights won’t come on at all.

Should I swap the traveler wires? Also important to point out that the load to the dimmer seems to be coming from another (properly working) dimmer switch.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The load from one dimmer switch shouldn't be coming from another dimmer switch.
Since the job was just completed, get the contractor back there to straighten out the lighting. Don't just start switching wires around until you've traced all of them out. If you screw something up, then the contractor's under no obligation to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, don't blow the warranty. You didn't even open up these boxes lol.